# Live TV streaming with Tvheadend works fine on laptop, but not on home server

Tags: linux, video, streaming, tv, kodi

I have a DVB-T TV tuner USB dongle (Afatech AF9013/AF9015) which I'm using in conjunction with the latest version of Tvheadened and the latest stable build of Kodi. I ultimately want my small home server to stream live TV to other devices on the network, but streaming is terrible on the server. I've tested the USB device on a laptop and it appears to work fine, so I'm not sure what's up.

On my old laptop running LXLE (based on Ubuntu 14.04) live TV streams almost perfectly through the USB DVB-T device - no stuttering, no artefacts, and I can watch the stream on other devices on the network. CPU is Core 2 Duo 2.00GHz with 2GB RAM and 128MB video card.

If I plug the same USB tuner into my HP ProLiant MicroServer N54L running Mint 17.1 the live TV stream is terrible quality - lots of stuttering and visual artefacts. This is true for local streaming as well as watching the stream from other devices on the network. The ProLiant has an AMD Turion 2.20GHz CPU with 6GB RAM and a 1GB video card.

Could someone suggest a good place to start poking around to try and find out why the TV tuner doesn't work on my ProLiant MicroServer? Maybe something to do with codecs...? I've no idea where to start looking.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Chris